# Snakemake: calling other subworkflow within file

Tags: bioinformatics, snakemake

How do I call a different snakemake workflow, with its own environment and configfile, as a part of my subworkflow?

I want to wrap a published snakemake workflow called MGEfinder with my code in order to automatically prepare its input files and deploy it in multiple subdirectories

1. I tried using `subworkflow` but the problem is that it runs first while I need it to run after a certain output is made
2. I was considering using `include` but it prevents me from using a unique environment or config file.
3. I was considering creating a third workflow to call both subworkflows but didn't try it yet and it would complicate my debugging
4. I was considering modifying the original code to include my 'env' of choice but it is (a) time-consuming (b) complicates my publication and (c) not ideal in terms of best practices
5. Finally, I made a conda rule that calls it. It works but my workflow sees it as one job and it is certainly far from best practices:

```
rule mgefinder:
        input:
            lambda wildcards: 
                expand("mgefinder/{group}/00.bam/{sample2}.{sample1}.bam.bai",
                    sample1=GROUPS.get(int(wildcards.group)), 
                    sample2=GROUPS.get(int(wildcards.group)), 
                    allow_missing=True),
            lambda wildcards: 
                expand("mgefinder/{group}/00.{dirname}/{sample}.fna",
                    sample=GROUPS.get(int(wildcards.group)), 
                    dirname=["assembly","genome"],allow_missing=True),
        output:
            "mgefinder/{group}/dummy.txt"
        params:
            prefix="mgefinder/{group}/"
        conda:
            "database/mgefinder.yaml"
        shell:
            "mgefinder workflow denovo {params.prefix}; touch {params.prefix}/dummy.txt"
```

Comment: I think you give a good summary of the problem actually...